# org-mode: Is there a description markup like in LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode

In org-mode, is there a markup like LaTeX's description?

```
\begin{description}
  \item[First] The first item
  \item[Second] The second item
  \item[Third] The third etc \ldots
\end{description}
```

Result:

[image]

Please note that the items are in bold face. and if the description is longer than one line, the second line (and the following line) would be indented right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Description lists are of the form

```
  - Keyword :: description of keyword, which may be as long as you like and 
      spread over several lines
  - Header :: description of header
```

These are rendered as `description` in LaTeX export.  `org-mode`s filling commands will correctly fill such items.  You can separate the list from other text by a blank line.

Comment: Wow, that's really simple yet powerful. Thank you.